# Facebook comment using ajax/django site

Tags: ajax, django, facebook, comments

I have just one trouble adding fb comments box in my site. I use kust one url and read the content of the site using js. I put in the head the init of my fb app   but I have three post in the main page  and I want one comment box for every post. To load the comments of my post I use ((myurl)){{post.id}} to make unique the comment box. This url dosen't exist. But show me up difference comment for every. But don't let me moderate.. I mean dont show the moderation tool. But if i change the href of the post to my url real. Show me the noderstion tool but the same comments in every posts. Any idea???

Comment: There is no other way than having the individual URLs return the relevant meta data. If those URLs “don’t exist” yet, then create them. (Although they should have already existed, otherwise this is a rather flawed system you’ve set up there.)

Answer (score 0):

The page is by ajax bwcause is a radio station and  need to listwn the station y all contwnt. There is any way to assign thw url "manualy" in thw api of fb?